# Display the total projected income (based on orders) of ‘Eat Well’ for April 2013 i have got the ans but

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

```
select  ((normalcost*25*0.5)+(schoolcost*25)) as "projectedcost" 
from    (   select  count(orderno) as normalcost 
            from    platterorder 
            where to_char(deliveryDate,'MON-YYYY')='APR-2013'
        ),
        (   select  count(orderno) as schoolcost 
            from    schoolorder 
            where to_char(deliveryDate,'MON-YYYY')='APR-2013'
        );
```

the above code works perfectly but when i try to add discountpercent column in place of 0.5 its showing errors

the related tables are as follows

```
PlatterOrder
(   orderNo, 
    deliveryDate, 
    deliveryTime, 
    invoiced, 
    isBulk, 
    platterQuantity, 
    discountPercent, 
    clientNo        
)

SchoolOrder
(   orderNo, 
    deliveryDate, 
    deliveryTime, 
    invoiced, 
    taxExPercent,
    clientNo
);
```

Comment: What error is it showing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow your code, but you aren't selecting discountpercent column anywhere.  It's not available to the SELECT clause because you're only selecting other fields in your two subqueries.  If your example works, and you only have one discount rate per month then something like:

```
select ((normalcost*25*0.5)+(schoolcost*25)) as "projectedcost" 
from (select count(orderno) as normalcost 
      from platterorder where to_char(deliveryDate,'MON-YYYY')='APR-2013')
  , (select count(orderno) as schoolcost 
     from schoolorder where to_char(deliveryDate,'MON-YYYY')='APR-2013');
  , (select DISTINCT discountpercent  as discountpercent  
     from platterorder where to_char(deliveryDate,'MON-YYYY')='APR-2013');
```

The whole construct is odd though, no joining, is discount rate only changing by month?

Comment: What flavor of sql allows comma separated values in the FROM clause?

Comment: the discount rate is 0.5 for everyclient in the table but can i use avg of discount rate in place of 0.5

Comment: im using sql plus of orcale db

Answer (score 0):

It's showing error because column discountPercent isn't declared anywhere within query - you need t somehow add it. What value of discountPercent you need? For example, if you wan't to use average for month, use the following query:

```
select  ((normalcost*25*avgdiscountPercent)+(schoolcost*25)) as "projectedcost" 
from    (   select  count(orderno) as normalcost 
            from    platterorder 
            where to_char(deliveryDate,'MON-YYYY')='APR-2013'
        ),
        (   select  count(orderno) as schoolcost 
            from    schoolorder 
            where to_char(deliveryDate,'MON-YYYY')='APR-2013'
        ),
        (select avg(discountPercent) as avgdiscountPercent
            from platterorder
            where to_char(deliveryDate,'MON-YYYY')='APR-2013'
        );
```